# Sort List by Date in Title

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datetime, format

I need to sort the list by date in the title if the title contains a date format(dd.MM.yyy). The code in cshtml is used from the model.
Ex:

"Example 20.01.2021" and "Examples 11.02.2021" to sort by date.

The title is of string type. I tried to convert it to a date with `DateTime.TryParse` but it is necessary to separate the date from the string to be able to convert it.

Here is part of my code:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b[0-9]{2}(\.|-)[0-9]{2}(\.|-)[0-9]{4}\b");

foreach (var document in Model.OrderBy(x => x.DocumentID).ThenByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(r.Match(x.Title).Value)
{....}
```

Comment: Create a custom `IComparer<string>` that pulls out the relevant substring to compare

Answer (score 0):

From the inbound data you can not identify if the date is `(dd/MM/yyyy)` or `(MM/dd/yyyy)`

Example:
Is the "12/01/2021" (dd/MM/yyyy) or a (MM/dd/yyyy)? We can not distinguish.

With that being said, if we assume that we know the format of the date then you could something like that:

```
string title = "Example 12.01.2021";
// Remove white spacing and letters
var date = String.Concat(title.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && !Char.IsLetter(c)));
DateTime dateValue;

var isMonthFirst = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM.dd.yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
var isDayFirst = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
if (isMonthFirst)
{
    // code
}
if (isDayFirst)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TryParseExact`, hence your date format is not standard. the other thing is you need to split date from title. If we assume that your date is at the end of the title line you can use substring, or split by space and take the last index.

Here is an example.

Les say this is your input:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>()
{
    "Example Title A 21.01.2021",
    "Example Title B 22.01.2021",
    "Example Title C 20.01.2021",
    "Example Title D 19.01.2021"
};
```

you can use SortedList to sort by inserting, that requires key value, in your case key is date and value is your title for instance.

```
SortedList<DateTime, string> sortedList = new SortedList<DateTime, string>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    string title = item.Substring(0, item.LastIndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal));
    string dateStr = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
    DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, new[] { "dd.mm.yyyy" }, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date);
    sortedList.Add(date, title);
}
```

Regarding`new[] { "dd.mm.yyyy" }`, in case you have other date formats you can added those to your array as well. Regarding style and culture, you can modify that depending on your final out come.

Now if you run the code you get

```
19/01/2021 00.01.00 Example Title D
20/01/2021 00.01.00 Example Title C
21/01/2021 00.01.00 Example Title A
22/01/2021 00.01.00 Example Title B
```

You can of course you normal List with object type and sort by date, or keep SortedList and the key is datetime and the value is your object type.